# Create a fully-functional derived class with just one extra method in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is what I want to do:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int someNewMethod(int someIntParam)
    {
       // Does something not in the base class
       return 0; // success
    }
};
```

Then I should be able to use Derived in place of Base (while fully aware that the reference may become invalid, depending on when the Base object is deleted):

```
Derived &d = *pointerToSomeExistingBaseObject;
d.someNewMethod(12);
```

While somewehere else in code, far, far away (and beforehand):

```
Base *pointerToSomeExistingBaseObject = new Base(...);
```

Thank you!

Comment: And do you expect to do this with new Base? A derived object has never been created.

Comment: A new function for an existing class (which cannot be changed) is actually a quite common case. Just make a free function which has a parameter of type `Base&` or `const Base&`. (It's anyway recommended as good style to not to implement member functions which could be made a free function as well.)

Answer (score 2):

> Create a fully-functional derived class with just one extra method in C++?

You can do that. You did that with `Derived` (assuming `someNewMethod` isn't in `Base`).

---

> ```
> Derived &d = *pointerToSomeExistingBaseObject;
> d.someNewMethod(12);
> ```
>
> While somewehere else in code, far, far away (and beforehand):
>
> ```
> Base *pointerToSomeExistingBaseObject = new Base(...);
> ```

No, you cannot do that. In order to call the non-static member functions of `Derived`, you must create an object of type `Derived` or a type derived from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected this may not work, although, conceptually, it should be no problem passing the 'this' pointer to a new function, not present in the original class description, but declared in a derived class _that adds no new data members!_

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to make the function free-standing:

```
int someNewMethod(Base& obj, int someIntParam)
{
    // Does something with obj that is not in Base
    return 0; // success
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is also what @Scheff'sCat suggested, thank you as well.
One could also create a wrapper class around base, something lightweight, like a smart pointer, that also adds the extra method:
    class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
        Derived(const Base* base) : m_pBase(base) {}
        int someNewMethod(int someIntParam)
        {
           // Does something not in the base class
           return 0; // success
        }
    private:
        Base *m_pBase;
    };
But that's more than I'd like to do.